# Can i create a dictionary to pull commands from?

Tags: python, chatbot

if im trying to get responses like i say
"Hello"
and get a random response in return (from the code below)
how would i make this work based off of what i say
like if i were to say "whats a name" and want a response from the name list instead
Can i pull that off with a Dict?

```
import random 

responseHello = [
"Hi!",
"Hello!",
"How can i help you?",
]
responseDict = {
                "hello" : "responseHello"
                }

h = input("say Hello:")
if h = responseDict["hello"]
 print(responseHello)
```

so as shown here (i know the bottom half certainly isnt right i just tried it)
what would i have to do in order to get my input to cause a different response?
so sorry if this doesnt make sense, i just learned of the dictionary command today and am trying to figure it out. any help is greatly appreciated!
(I know i should try following some tutorial for chatbots but everytime i do tensorflow doesnt work at all)

Comment: Use the list itself as a dictionary value, and then use the result of the lookup directly - because that will be the list that you want. To make a random choice from the list, use the appropriately named `random.choice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the if statement as below and it should work.

```
import random

if h in resoponseDict:
  print(random.choice(responseHello))
```

Edit: get random element in response Hello

Answer (score 1):

```
import random 

responseHello = [
"Hi!",
"Hello!",
"How can i help you?",
]
responseDict = {
        "hello" : "responseHello"
        }

h = input("say Hello:")
if h in responseDict:
    n = random.randint(0,2)
    print(responseHello[n])
```

this will work^